# Angular - Scroll down to bottom automatically when opening angular dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

I have a problem with angular material dialog in my project,
When I opened a dialog it scroll down to bottom automatically and when I close the dialog, it scroll back to the original position before opening it.

I tried to :

- add `autoFocus: false` in my dialog config
- change `BrowserAnimationModule` to `NoopAnimationModule` in my app.module.ts file
- add `tabindex="-1"` in my button tag in dialog content

but nothing has worked, I use a custom CSS theme without any JS files,
I only use material to use dialog.

Here is my code :

```
public openAddLinkDialog(): void {
   this.dialog.open(AddLinkComponent).afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
   });
}

<div class="modal modal-right fade show" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Ajouter un lien</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="closeDialog()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body ps-container ps-theme-default">
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer modal-footer-uniform">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-bold btn-pure btn-secondary" (click)="closeDialog()">
          Fermer
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-bold btn-pure btn-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="addLink()">
          Ajouter
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

Comment: can you please upload code on stackblitz?

Answer (score 3):

Add a configuration object when opening the window with setting `autoFocus: false`
For example, here:
`const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( SomeComponent, { autoFocus: false });`
Otherwise, the window will be scrolled to the first focusable element, i.e. your button